Aliases conflict with cultureKey contexts
the problem is that if the alias on any of the contexts starts with de, for example development-of-documentation, I am taken to the 404 page of the German context. I realize that the de key is the problem, but how can I fix this. Here is the code that defines the context:
<?php
if($modx->context->get('key') != "mgr"){
    switch ($_REQUEST['cultureKey']) {
        case 'ru':
            $modx->switchContext('ru');
            break;
        case 'it':
            $modx->switchContext('it');
            break;
        case 'fr':
            $modx->switchContext('fr');
            break;
        case 'de':
            $modx->switchContext('de');
            break;
        case 'es':
            $modx->switchContext('es');
            break;
        case 'uk':
            $modx->switchContext('web');
            break;
        case 'ua':
            $modx->switchContext('web');
            break;
        default:
            $modx->switchContext('en');
            break;
    }
    unset($_GET['cultureKey']);
}


How do you set $_REQUEST['cultureKey']. Is it created via .htaccess or are you on nginx?
